# Why my site isn't fully functioning on public domain (in the world wide web)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, web-hosting

I made a simple website. The site is fully functionable in my localhost (my computer). Everything working fine here.

But problem arises when I upload the files into the web server in order for running that in public domain. There, no content is showing except the layout. No link or tab is working, no paragraph inside the body is displaying. You may have a look [here](http://jabiralfatah.com/).

For what reason?

I uploaded all the files (with source code) associated my website except the images and videos (since there are a lots of images and I will upload it a bit later).

*[NOTE: I have xampp local server installed in my computer. All the
sourse codes files are stored inside the htdocs folder. Inside the
htdocs folder I have a folder named jquery(which was installed with
the package). I saved my .JS file inside the JQuery folder (since I
used jquery code too). So when I upload file into the server do I need
to upload the whole htdocs folder? Or how about the JQuery folder
(which contains the JQuery source code)? Do I also need to upload it?*

My paths set are the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery [contains the whole project's source file]         
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery\js  [Contains only JavaScript&JQuery file]
```

Comment: The problem probably has something to do with the server's path differing from your own. It would be best to make these paths dynamic, or use them from the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

I tried debugging the HTML on your website. I found the following code in design.css at line number 258

```
#all_contents >div {
display:none;
}
```

Once you remove this(display:none), all the content is available on the website link that you shared.
Also, I am not sure why this is working on your local. Are you sure that you have uploaded the same version which is running in your local?
You can debug your webpage by pressing F12 and then selecting the problematic area. On the right hand side, you can see the css rules associated with the selected element.

For getting the specific content in a page and not all, create a new file by the name who_im.html and put your content over there and then You should do something like 
    About Me
Like this you will have to make other pages as well and add the hyper links to the menu in every page.

Comment: yes, i did it. it solves the problem, but also causes another problem. the whole webcontents are now in one page, in my case under the  HOME tab. look here please: http://jabiralfatah.com/

Comment: Actually, that is happening because you have coded the page in that way only. You are using internal anchor tags to link (/#who_im)
You should be using external Anchor tags for the thing that you are talking about. You can refer the following link about the use of Anchor tags [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: yes but if u see my jQuery code then you know: 
/*Make the tabs work-begins*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#all_contents>div').filter(':first').show();
$('ul>li>a').click(function () {
        $('#all_contents>div').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
        return false;
    });
 });
 /*Make the tabs work-ends*/                                                              Also its working fine in my localhost and jsfiddle too. See here: jsfiddle.net/yb6urd6x

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your page and look where you expect the content to be, you'll find `<div id="home">`.  Looking at the CSS for this, it shows line 258 of your css file has this:

```
#all_contents >div {
display:none;
}
```

This is causing all of your contents to not display. Removing this will fix the problem.

Also, if you look on the browser's console when your page loads, you'll notice a lot of 404s trying to load various scripts, stylesheets, and images. That's potentially contributing to the problem. I'd focus on fixing those first, to make sure everything is loading properly.

Comment: thanks, This helps. but after changing, it causes another problem. All the pages are now under the home tab! But it shouldn't be in that way. Clicking a different tab doesn't make any difference. like the whole site is under Home menu. WHy so. Please look here the updated version: jabiralfatah.com

Comment: Spend some time debugging in the browser using Firebug or Chrome's dev tools before giving up - I assume your navigation buttons are meant to change the visibility of various areas, but there's something not working with the init. At the very least, this will give you more details to your problem, and in the best case, you'll have an AHA moment and be able to fix it yourself.

Comment: i will try hard. but do u think that i have to change the whole design eventually? or it can be done with little effort? I am frustrated. because thats not what i expected. My site works exactly how i want in my localhost, but in the public doamin, i see that  it just directs me to the different sections in the same page. The link doesn't take me to the different page.

Comment: See edit - you can see the console in Chrome by pressing F12 and going to the console tab. One or more of those missing files is likely part of the problem.

Comment: i simply fixed that, i added an extra link with a page named style.css.  but it doesn't exist, thats why i remove it from my source code. this error is fixed. but as u know that i dont waant all the contents in the one page. Right now clicking on a tab doesn't direct me to another page, rather it just shows me the contents in the same page. In my localhost it was working fine. oce i upload the files into the server, it behaves like this. it also works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/yb6urd6x/